# Getting error when trying to 'go get' the geos package

Tags: go

i have tried to run a new project of golang i've  installed everything but I faced the following problem

```
$ go get github.com/paulsmith/gogeos/geos
#### #github.com/paulsmith/gogeos/geos
In file included from ..\..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\paulsmith\gogeos@v0.1.2\geos\coordseq.go:4:
./geos.h:1:10: fatal error: geos_c.h: No such file or directory

    1 | #include <geos_c.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [installation instructions on the project's page](https://github.com/paulsmith/gogeos), it seems like you have to install GEOS first; see this part: https://github.com/paulsmith/gogeos#requirements

It can be as easy as `$ apt-get install libgeos-dev` on Ubuntu, but the link above has instructions for a from-source installation as well.

What happens in your case is that the Go package likely uses `cgo` to load C code from GEOS, and it fails immediately because GEOS is not installed, and `cgo` cannot find the headers files.

Comment: but what is the case for windows they don't show the installation guide

Comment: @leopoldservatius: on Windows, sounds like "From source (all OSes)" is the part for you